# Sentence monstrosity!

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Check out this horrendous sentence I just managed to create:

*This blanket, Holden talks about as if it were some novelty that Mr. Spencer having bought it shows how “lame” old people such as his history teacher are.*

I'm curious as to how I could make this sentence better, and if this is even grammatically correct as it is now.

(Yes, this is about the Catcher in the Rye and no, it's not a homework question.)

Comment: Even though Holden speaks about it as if it were novel, the blanket, which was bought by his history teacher Mr. Spencer, shows how old people are 'lame'. I haven't read the book (should I be ashamed?) so I am not sure why 'lame' is in quotes.

Comment: Hi, kukac, and welcome to ELU. Please feel free to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
 and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)
 for guidance on how to use this site to your best advantage.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting exercise in bringing both semantic and structural coherence to your query sentence, while 1) simultaneously also maintaining the emphasis on the remark being made about the lameness of old people, and 2) avoiding the potential awkwardness from inserting the parenthetical reference to Mr Spencer into the remark, which isolates the verb 'are' right at the end of the sentence.

I came up with the following:

> Holden talks about this blanket as if it were some novelty that shows how lame old people — just like his history teacher Mr. Spencer, who bought it — are.

Here, I decided that dashes (which are more dynamic than commas or parentheses) represented the best choice of punctuation versus either of these alternatives:

> Holden talks about this blanket as if it were some novelty that shows how lame old people (just like his history teacher Mr. Spencer, who bought it) are.

---

> Holden talks about this blanket as if it were some novelty that shows how lame old people, just like his history teacher Mr. Spencer, who bought it, are.

It's still not entirely satisfactory (partly because I wasn't able to move *are* away from the end of the sentence, and partly because *how lame old people* has garden-path potential), but it's the best I can come up with at the moment.

Perhaps someone else will be able to do better...